# Expand mat-expansion-panel using open method in selector

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-6

Expand `mat-expansion-panel` using open method in `selector(mat-expansion-panel)`

I am using `mat-expanison-panel` in my application and I already have a ref. to it in my .ts file.

`@ViewChild('expansionPanel') public expansionPanel: MatExpansionModule`;

```
<mat-expansion-panel #expansionPanel class="expansion-card" [expanded]="flashcardInputExpanded" [disabled]="!collapsable">
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
```

I am trying to expand the `panel` on a fn call, something like this.

```
  open() {
    this.expansionPanel.open();
  }
```

but the concern is that it is not working, panel is not getting expanded by invoking `this.expansionPanel.open();`.

Reference api panel  -  https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/api

In my case `mat-expansion-panel` is inside `sidenav`,

```
@ViewChild('sidenav') public sidenav: MatSidenav;
```

So what happens is this is how it looks, initially once I open the `sidenav`.

[image]

but when I close the sidenav component and opens it again, then this is how it looks.

[image]

keeping in mind that we have only one prop in this `mat-expansion-panel` that is [expanded]="true".

Comment: Try @ViewChild('expansionPanel') public expansionPanel: MatExpansionPanel

Comment: Did you try manually setting the MatExpansionPanelState property to 'expanded'?

Comment: let me edit the question.

Comment: @FrancoRoura I manually added  [expanded]="true". but even if I close the side-nav and opens it again expansion panel is collapsed, as mentioned in edited question.

Comment: Then try erasing every listener/emitter that might be affecting the expansionPanel's state and use `[expanded]="sidenav.opened"` in order to keep the panel's state sync ed with the sidenav's CdkScrollable state.

Comment: thanks @FrancoRoura but is even if I hardcode its value to true in html  [expanded]="true" this thing collapses when I open the sidebar, that's the concern and the strange thing is that once sidebar is opened and this thing is collapsed, and i expand it by clicking it, then if I close the sidebar and opens it again and again this things remains expanded that's the exact behaviour I want like remain expanded, but on the very first time user opens the sidebar without a need to expand it manually.

Comment: Well, MatSidenav has an event emitter that'll be triggered every time it starts opening, did you try listening to `sidenav.openedStart()` and triggering `this.expansionPanel.open();` inside of it?

Comment: Please post a full working example - I can't get it to NOT work: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qwrvq5?file=app/sidenav-open-close-example.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the expansion panel input variable `expanded`. In your case, you already have the variable `flashcardInputExpanded` defined.

```html
<mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="flashcardInputExpanded">
```

You can do something like this:

```js
open() {
  this.flashcardInputExpanded = true;
}
```

Comment: it's not working that's why I tried to do it with function.

Comment: That's strange, it should work. Are you using change detection onpush?